# I'm getting this error: The "data-pay-btn" BUTTON element does not have the specified CSS

Tags: css

The data-pay-btn BUTTON should have a fixed position, 90% width, solid border of 1px and positioned 20px from the bottom of the viewport.

```
[data-pay-btn]{
      position: fixed;
      width: 90%;
      border: 1px solid;
      bottom: 20px;
  }
```

I'm getting this error:

> The "data-pay-btn" BUTTON element does not have the specified CSS.

HTML Question is:

Create a BUTTON as a sibling to the data-credit-card DIV. Set the BUTTON's class to mdc-button and give it a data-pay-btn attribute. It should have Pay & Checkout Now as its display text. After the user enters details of the card and clicks on this button, the app will strike-though the card numbers to indicate that they are in-valid.

MY HTML CODES:

```
<div data-cart-info>
          <h1 class="mdc-typography--headline4">
              <span class="material-icons"> shopping_cart </span>
              <span data-bill>$10</span>
         </h1>
    </div>
    <div data-credit-card class="mdc-card mdc-card--outlined">
        <div class="mdc-card__primary-action">

            <img data-card-type src="https://placehold.it/120x60.png?text=Card">
            <div data-cc-digits>
                <input type="text" size="4" placeholder="----" />
                <input type="text" size="4" placeholder="----" />
                <input type="text" size="4" placeholder="----" />
                <input type="text" size="4" placeholder="----" />

            </div>
            <div data-cc-info>
                <input type="text" size="20" placeholder="Name Surname" />
                <input class="second" type="text" size="6" placeholder="MM/YY" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="mdc-button" data-pay-btn=""> Pay &amp; Checkout Now </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your CSS is fine. The problem lies elsewhere. I assume your CSS doesn't target the right element, but there's no way for us to know without you providing your HTML.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57280638/edit) with additional details and code to include a [mcve] instead of providing them in comments.

Answer (score 0):

**please use**

```
      .mdc-button{


          position:fixed;
          width:90%;
          border-width:1px;
          border-style:solid;
          bottom:20px;

      }
``
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. However the button should be after the last div

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
button[data-pay-btn]{
        position:fixed;
        width:90%;
        border:solid 1px;
        bottom:20px;
    }
```

You must put your button (bellow the div like that:

This Button is a sibbling to the data-credit-card DIV not a child

```
<div data-cart-info>
        <h1 class="mdc-typography--headline4">
            <span class="material-icons">shopping_cart</span>
            <span data-bill></span>
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div data-credit-card class="mdc-card mdc-card--outlined">
        <div class="mdc-card__primary-action">
            <img data-card-type src="https://placehold.it/120x60.png?text=Card" />
            <div data-cc-digits>
                <input type="text" size="4" placeholder="----" />
                <input type="text" size="4" placeholder="----" />
                <input type="text" size="4" placeholder="----" />
                <input type="text" size="4" placeholder="----" />
            </div>
            <div data-cc-info>
                <input type="text" size="20" placeholder="Name Surname" />
                <input type="text" size="6" placeholder="MM/YY" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <button data-pay-btn class="mdc-button">Pay Now</button>
```

by the way how did you style your "data-credit-card" DIV ?